# In what sense are coroutines dual to (sub)routines?

Tags: pl.programming-languages, ct.category-theory

The name [*coroutine*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coroutine) suggests that in some sense they should be dual to (sub)routines. Is there a real mathematical duality? I'm hoping for something like "in category theory subroutines are X and coroutines are Y, where X is dual to Y".

Comment: If there is a connection, it would be via continuations.

Comment: Which incidentally are not dual to ntinuations.

Comment: “Regrettably, the world of computing seems better at coining new terms for old meanings (or without any meaning at all).” © Edsger W. Dijkstra, EWD854.

Comment: The prefix 'co' isn't always category theoretic. A coconut isn't equivalent to a nut.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think this a misanalysis of the "co" prefix in this case.

"Coroutine" is "co" in the sense of "co-worker"; something that works together with another.

The term precedes by a long way the gross overuse for programming concepts of the prefix "co" in the Category Theoretic sense of a dual of another concept.

(Yes, there is editorial content there. ;-) )